# Add comma to a string as string moves from one list to another to a third list in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping

None of the other questions address this specifically so now I'm asking.

I'm web-scraping the following web page:
https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?Submit=StoreIM&Depa=3&Category=223

I was able to get the basic output into a csv file with no problem. My challenge is in making the scraped data fall under the appropriate column headings and be formatted appropriately for easy viewing and management.

I'm scraping newegg.com for laptops for sale. Since there's a lot of variation between laptop descriptions, I thought I would create code that tries to put the laptop attributes into the same headings. So for example, manufacturer information would be under 'product_name' and would be in a list called `mkr_list`. The `mkr_list` would be:

```
mkr_list = ["ASUS", "Lenovo", "MSI", "Acer", "HP", "Hewlett-Packard", "Dell", "Microsoft"]
```

Microprocessor information would be under the `prcsr_name` column, and would look like this:
`prcsr_list = ["Intel", "AMD", "Core", "i3*", "i5*", "i7*", "CPU"]`, and would be descriptions around Intel or AMD processors. Other descriptors and lists would follow for displays, Hard drives and so on. 
Ideally, the output from the code should look like this:

[image: Intended output of code]

While the `csv.file` seems to be created with no problem, it appears that my attempt to include specific strings in lists so that the code loops through lists and then matches a list to put into a file doesn't seem to work. My code looks like this.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?Submit=StoreIM&Depa=3&Category=223'
uClient = uReq(my_url) 
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "item-container"})
container = containers[0]

mkr_list = ["ASUS", "Lenovo", "MSI", "Acer", "HP", "Hewlett-Packard", "Dell", "Microsoft"]
model_list = ["VivoBook", "ZenBook", "S14", "S432", "Thin", "and", "Light"]
display_list = ["13*", "14*", "15*", "16*", "17*", "18*"]
prcsr_list = ["Intel", "AMD", "Core", "i3*", "i5*", "i7*", "CPU"]
ram_list = ["8", "GB", "RAM"]
hd_size = ["512", "GB", "PCI*", "NVM*", "SSD"]

filename = "laptops16.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "product_name, model_name, display_list, prcsr_name, RAM, HD_size, graphics_card, camera, 
color, OS, price\n"

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
     title_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
     product_name = title_container[0].text
     match_1 = [s for s in mkr_list if s in product_name]
     match_2 = [t for t in model_list if t in product_name]
     match_3 = [u for u in display_list if u in product_name]
     match_4 = [v for v in prcsr_list if v in product_name]
     match_5 = [w for w in ram_list if w in product_name]
     match_6 = [x for x in hd_size if x in product_name]

     price_container = container.findAll("li", {"class": "price-current"})
     price = price_container[0].text.strip().replace("\xa0\r\n", "").replace("\n", "").replace(",", 
     "")

     print("product_name: " + str(match_1))
     print("model_name: " + str(match_2))
     print("display_list: " + str(match_3))
     print("price: " + price)

     f.write(product_name + "," + price.replace("TSh", "") + "\n")
   f.close()
```

I'm grateful for any assistance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use pandas here to create that table.

You still need to work out some of the regex to pull out display size and what not, but this will get you going.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
import pandas as pd

my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?Submit=StoreIM&Depa=3&Category=223'
uClient = uReq(my_url) 
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "item-container"})
container = containers[0]

mkr_list = ["ASUS", "Lenovo", "MSI", "Acer", "HP", "Hewlett-Packard", "Dell", "Microsoft"]
model_list = ["VivoBook", "ZenBook", "S14", "S432", "Thin", "and", "Light"]
display_list = ["13*", "14*", "15*", "16*", "17*", "18*"]
prcsr_list = ["Intel", "AMD", "Core", "i3*", "i5*", "i7*", "CPU"]
ram_list = ["8", "GB", "RAM"]
hd_size = ["512", "GB", "PCI*", "NVM*", "SSD"]





result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['product_name', 'maker','model_name', 'display', 'prcsr_name', 'RAM', 'HD_size', 'graphics_card', 'camera', 'color', 'OS', 'price'])



for container in containers:
     title_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
     product_name = title_container[0].text
     mkr = ' '.join([s for s in mkr_list if s in product_name])
     model = ' '.join([t for t in model_list if t in product_name])
     display = ' '.join([u for u in display_list if u in product_name])
     prcsr = ' '.join([v for v in prcsr_list if v in product_name])
     ram = ' '.join([w for w in ram_list if w in product_name])
     hd = ' '.join([x for x in hd_size if x in product_name])

     graphics = ''
     camera = ''
     color = ''
     opSys = ''

     price_container = container.findAll("li", {"class": "price-current"})
     price = price_container[0].text.strip().replace("\xa0\r\n", "").replace("\n", "").replace(",", "")

     temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[product_name, mkr, model, display, prcsr, ram, hd, graphics, camera, color, opSys, price ]],
                            columns = ['product_name', 'maker','model_name', 'display', 'prcsr_name', 'RAM', 'HD_size', 'graphics_card', 'camera', 'color', 'OS', 'price'])


     result = result.append(temp_df, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

     print("product_name: " + str(mkr))
     print("model_name: " + str(model))
     print("display_list: " + str(display))
     print("price: " + price)



filename = "laptops16.csv"
result.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (result.to_string())
                                         product_name   maker                        model_name display      prcsr_name       RAM     HD_size graphics_card camera color OS                 price
0   ASUS VivoBook S15 S532 Thin & Light 15.6" FHD,...    ASUS               VivoBook Thin Light          Intel Core CPU  8 GB RAM  512 GB SSD                                 $729.99 (3 Offers)–
1   Lenovo Laptop 100e 81CYX503US Intel Celeron N3...  Lenovo                                                     Intel      8 GB          GB                                $249.99            –
2   ASUS VivoBook S14 S432 Thin and Light 14" FHD,...    ASUS  VivoBook S14 S432 Thin and Light          Intel Core CPU  8 GB RAM  512 GB SSD                                 $699.99 (4 Offers)–
3   HP Chromebook 11-v000nr 11.6" Chromebook - 136...      HP                                                            8 GB RAM          GB                                 $199.99 (2 Offers)–
4   Lenovo ThinkPad X280, 12.5" FHD, UHD Graphics ...  Lenovo                              Thin                          8 GB RAM      GB SSD                                 $939.99 (3 Offers)–
5   Lenovo IdeaPad 130 Laptop, 15.6" HD Display, A...  Lenovo                                                       AMD  8 GB RAM  512 GB SSD                                $549.00            –
6   HP EliteBook 840 G3 Notebook, 14" FHD Display,...      HP                                                Intel Core  8 GB RAM      GB SSD                                $699.99            –
7   ASUS ZenBook 14 Ultra-Slim Laptop 14" Full HD ...    ASUS                           ZenBook                 AMD CPU  8 GB RAM  512 GB SSD                                 $779.99 (2 Offers)–
8   MSI Laptop Modern 14 A10RAS-884 Intel Core i5 ...     MSI                                                Intel Core      8 GB  512 GB SSD                                 $799.00 (4 Offers)–
9   ASUS ZenBook Pro Duo UX581 15.6" 4K UHD NanoEd...    ASUS                           ZenBook              Intel Core  8 GB RAM      GB SSD                                $2450.99 (5 Offers)–
10  ASUS ZenBook 14 Ultra Thin and Light Laptop, 4...    ASUS            ZenBook Thin and Light              Intel Core  8 GB RAM  512 GB SSD                                 $799.99 (2 Offers)–
11  ASUS ZenBook 13 Ultra-Slim Durable Laptop 13.3...    ASUS                           ZenBook              Intel Core    GB RAM  512 GB SSD                                $999.99            –
12  HP Laptop ProBook 450 G6 (5VC00UT#ABA) Intel C...      HP                                                Intel Core      8 GB      GB SSD                                $829.61 (11 Offers)–
```

Comment: You’re right it is tricky, but I don’t think it’s impossible. Might be a nice machine learning project with NLP to pull out those entities.

Comment: Yes, I've added more terms and attributes but its not quite perfect. Still a challenge but you got me started in a good direction.